# Alexa node.js http request with authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, alexa-skills-kit

I'm implementing a skill for Amazon Alexa.I want to determine the user's geolocation, but the http.get request is not working. I tried the request in postman and I get the desired result, but couldn't figure out what could be the problem. The request url should be like this `https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/{deviceId}/settings/address` with the Authorization header `Authorization: Bearer {token}`. 
Here is my code

```
try{
    var body = "";
    console.log('Authorization ', consentToken);
    var response = '';

    var options = {
      host: 'api.eu.amazonalexa.com',
      path: '/v1/devices/'+deviceId+'/settings/address',
      port: '443',
      headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer "+consentToken},
      method: 'GET'
    };       

    https.get(options, function(res) {
         console.log('status', res.statusCode);
         if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 400) {
           res.on('data', function(data_) { response += data_.toString(); });
           res.on('end', function() {
             var data = JSON.parse(response);
             console.log('data', data);
             if (data.length > 0)
                 userLocation = data;
           });
         }
       }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.log("errrrror",e);
       }).on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
                console.log('uncaughtException',err);
       });
  }
  catch(error) { 
        console.log('getAndProcessUserLocation',error);
}
```

I don't know why the https.get is not executed. No error is thrown, but I couldn't get any log from it.
 I followed the documentation from thr official site
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/device-address-api

Comment: In the question you mention `https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/device...`, in your code I see `api.eu.amazonalexa.com...` is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of your code, my guess is that you are not indicating to the Alexa request that you are handling it asynchronously, so the session is ending before the request completes.

Comment: What is the best practice when handling asynch requests?

Comment: That will depend on which Alexa SDK or framework you are using. I am using alexa-app, and in that framework I just need to return a Promise from the intent handler.